# My Minecraft LAN button won't let me turn it on? [ Minecraft PE 0.15.6 ]

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I  have been trying to connect to each other on Minecraft PE, but it has not been working. I know what I need to do to fix it - turn the LAN switch on.  However it is not letting me? Is there something wrong with my phone or the app?

Comment: Are you connecting via school wifi? You need a wifi connection that doesn't block the Lan.

Answer (score 1):

Are you inside the world when doing so? If so, it is impossible. You can only do it when nobody is in the world. If you are not, and are accessing it from the settings out of the world, then it is most likely hardware related.

Answer (score 0):

2 things,

1. LAN stands for Local Area Network. This means that if your friend is not connected to YOUR network, you CANNOT play together
2. If you are both on the same network you either have to be

   1. Connected to a Network
      Or
   2. Accessing the LAN settings from the main screen (Not In-Game)

Answer (score 0):

First you must make certain that you're on the same WiFi connection.

Second you need to make sure that the connection is not firewalled or if it is that it is open for Minecraft PE to access.

You also need to be sure that the port that the game uses is available which is 19132.  This means both the firewall and router have this port open/not blocked.

A side note, some versions had a bug that if you were not signed into Xbox account you couldn't play over LAN. This should be fixed in most recent version.

Lastly, typically the game defaults to open to LAN setting, but this needs to be turned on prior to loading the world if it's not already on.

Another side note, some networks/routers disallow remote device discovery. Make sure your firewall is allowing your computer to be discovered/seen. The mobile device should work as is.